# router push a locale route in nuxt with nuxt-i18n

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I use nuxt-i18n to get internationalization in my application. I have a list of news that gives me routes like that :

```
myapp.com/news (default language English)
myapp.com/fr/news
myapp.com/it/news
```

when i click on a news i want to reach th _id page to get only only the news i clicked on. so i did this in a method (onclick) :

```
onLoadNews(id) {this.$router.push("/news/" + id);}
```

But this way I always return to English default language. How to push a locale route (in the function of a method)  this way?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

this.$router.push(this.localePath({ name: "news-id", params: { id } }));

that worked for me because i have a folder "news" and inside two vue pages the index.vue and the _id.vue.

Comment: thanks, worth to notice that adding the `_id.vue` makes change the route name to `news-id`.

Comment: How can I navigate to a route programmatically including the current language?

Currently it looks like this but it always navigates to the main language.
```this.$router.push({ path: `step/${this.currentStep + 1}` });```

Every step is single page e.g. `step/1`or `step/2`